# My for loops code problem. Keeps repeating the amount of the last number digit

Tags: c++

Here is the question :
First, read in an input value for variable numIn. Then, read numIn integers from input and output each integer on a newline after the string "quantity= ".

Ex: If the input is 3 35 5 55, then the output is:

quantity= 35

quantity= 5

quantity= 55

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int numIn;
    int i;

    cin >> numIn;

    for (i = 0; i < numIn; ++i) {
        cin >> numIn;
        cout << "quantity= " << numIn << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It will repeat 55 until the whole loop reaches 55 iterations. So it will output all numbers but has 55 repeating like 52 times
I understand why it repeats the same amount of times when it comes to the last digit. It just repeats how many times whatever the last digit is. I've tried replacing the "i < numIn" to " i < 3 " and it passes that particular input test. Although other inputs when testing have more numbers, the loop cuts off before the other numbers are outputted. How can I have the code output however many amount of numbers inputted without getting it to repeat the last digit over and over until it reaches it? Aslo, when inputting negative numbers it will only output one number, so I guess only completes the loop once? Why is this the case? because you can't have negative iterations? what is wrong with the code?? Am I missing anything? Please help me. I am new to this website, so my apologies if any of this looks off (I had trouble formatting this code to the website's standard). I'm learning c++

Comment: `i = 0; i < numIn; ++i` you probably didn't mean to read `cin >> numIn` inside your loop

Comment: You should probably have a separate `quantity` variable, and use that inside the loop.

Comment: @AndyG what do you mean by "didn't mean to read "in >> numIn"? I added that to the loop so that I the numbers would show up correctly. without cin >> numIn inside the loop it will just repeat quantity: 3 for how many numbers inputted. Am I supposed to have the cin >> numIn formatted differently in the loop somehow? thanks for your time answering. I appreciate it.

Comment: @BoP what do you mean "have a separate quantity variable"? Like another int variable? I already have two.  If I added another one, how could I add it into the current code to produce my desired results? I am also going off of a pre-made code in an exercise on zybooks for c++. It doesn't say include another variable in the instructions. It also doesn't state to add "int i;" into the code either. I added that because I don't know how else you can have a for loop without it. Am I supposed to be using a while loop instead somehow?

Comment: Your loop is not correct. `numIn` is the number of iterations to perform, but since you keep reading in another `numIn` the iterations increase to that number. Also, you mean to put `i++` not `++i`, `++i` will cause you to miss a part of the iteration.

Comment: @AliasCartellano what do you mean "you keep reading in another numIn"? which part do you mean? the cin >> numIn part? I only included that so it could take the actual numbers inputed. If I were to take that out of the loop I would only get repeated "quantity: 3". How do I take that part out and still get the actual values for what is inputed? thanks for your time. Also I meant to use ++i because that is what I've been told to do in this exercise I am on. Please re-read the question given.

Comment: `numIn` is used to tell the loop when to stop. If you change `numIn` then the loop will also change to stop at that value. You need to use another integer variable to store the numbers being read and then output that integer.

Comment: @AliasCartellano I made int numOut and replaced the numIn in the loop with the new one and it worked just fine. Thank you very much. I wish I would have tried adding another variable. The exercise didn't say that I needed to and my professor tells us not to add anything so I was so confused. I literally spent hours on this exercise. Thank you so much again!